# Wordpress Contact Form 7 Redirect on radio button value not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I've been researching Contact Form 7 redirects based on values for the past 5 hours.  I cannot explain why my code doesn't work.  Can anyone see a problem?

Contact Form Radio Button

```
[radio radio-935 id:rating label_first "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10"]
```

Additional Settings

```
on_sent_ok: " if (document.getElementById('rating').value=='9') {location.replace('http://www.google.com')} else { location.replace('http://www.msn.com/') } "
```

When I select radio button 9, I am redirected to msn (the else argument).  All other values also go to MSN (at least that part is right).  I've tried changing the additional settings to a triple equals sign === but that didn't help.  I've also tried adding a pipe (|) after each value in the Radio Button.  That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the generated HTML and you'll know why your code doesn't work as expected. There are 2 options

#### The hard way

Define a function in a external JS file which iterates through the radio buttons

```
function getRating(radioName) {
  var ratings = document.getElementsByName( radioName );

  for( var r in ratings ) {
    if( ratings[r].checked )
      return ratings[r].value;
  }
  
  return null;
}
```

and then `on_sent_ok: if( getRating( "radio-935 ") == 9 ) { location.replace('http://www.google.com') } else { location.replace('http://www.msn.com') }`

#### The easy way :-)

`on_sent_ok: if( $( "input[name='radio-935']:checked" ).val() == 9 ) { location.replace('http://www.google.com') } else { location.replace('http://www.msn.com') }`

Comment: Due to my limited skill set (have only ever built inside wordpress), I opted for the easy way.

If I understand this correctly, it looks like I wasn't calling to see if the radio button was checked before grabbing value...

I changed the .val () == 9 ) to .val() >8 ).  Function seems to work still.  

Thank you so very much for taking the time to help me.  I've checked your answer as the correct one.  I tried to +1 but SO says I need more rep.  Please let me know if there is anything else I can do to increase your rep on SO.

Comment: Kevin, yes you need to loop the radio button and check if the radio button was selected and then get its value, as shown in the "hard way", fortunately jQuery will do that for us :) . Thanks for accepting my answer and not to worry about the reps, at the end of the day all that matters is I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This one is very easy way

on_sent_ok: "var sol = $("input[name=radio-935]:checked").val();if(sol == '9'){ location = 'http://google.com'; } else { location = 'http://msn.com'; }"